# Unable to deploy Node RED on IBM cloud Lite

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, node-red

I've registered to IBM Cloud Lite yesterday and my first, and only, app deployed was Node-RED App. But, when I select Cloud Foundry to configure the Deployment Automation, I receive the following message: "This option isn't available for your account type. Upgrade your account to continue."

[image: IBM Cloud Message].

And this stops me from continuing the configuration.

I configured the app details as follows:

- Resource Group: Default
- Tags: None
- Platform: Node.js

And the Service Details as:

- Region: London
- Resource Group: Default
- Pricing plan: Lite

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that IBM has changed what is available for Lite accounts created after 12th August 2021. You no longer get any Cloud Foundry memory so it will not be possible to run Node-RED without signing up for a paid account.

You may want to look at when the billing kicks in on the paid account to see if it's possible to run Node-RED under those limits, but I have not tried.

Account information [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts)